# Will Django allow requests from multiple Ajax function with one AjaxSetup that contains csrf?

Tags: ajax, django

The title can't handle my question completely, sorry.

I have three Ajax function in my Django template. First one sends comment requests, the second one updates a value to database and the third one manages login/register process.

All of them are being triggered by a button. As you know, Django says that use CSRF on your Ajax requests too. So, I use like this:

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
  // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
  return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}


var csrftoken = $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val();
$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
    if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    }
  }
});
```

Can this function handle all my Ajax requests in one template? Do I need to do extra stuff?

Comment: Haven't you tried clicking one of those buttons?

Comment: @SachinKukreja they're always working good.. I still don't know how they're working. Ask why.. My Ajax requests still working even if the $.ajaxSetup  isn't there.. (I'm using class-based views.)

Comment: Is there a `CsrfMiddleware` in your `MIDDLEWARE` setting?

Comment: @SachinKukreja yes, there is; the default Django setting file has it. `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware`

Comment: Are your views ones that require a csrf token, ie decorated with @csrf_protect etc?

Comment: @Bott0610 I didn't use something like that. Because, generic views already has the ability to send and check CSRF tokens as far as I know. Why?

Comment: @InterestingKnox Ah, missed the line about using class based views, but to answer your question; if they don't require a token then of course you wouldn't need to set up your ajax calls with one. I could be wrong but I don't think all class based views require a token. Would need to see your views.py and possibly your $.ajax functions to know more.